# handling and saving ManyToMany data from template - Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a template with a form. i'm using the scala Helper to handle data form and save it as a Model object. As you can see in my example the ***helper.select*** field will work with a ***ManytoOne*** not ***ManyToMany***. Now i want my form to allow selecting multiples categories and saving the model. Can i do that with form helper or i have to do this with the traditional way.

**the view:**

```
(..)
@helper.form(action = routes.Admin.newItem(), 'id -> "item_form", 'method -> "POST", 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data"){
        <fieldset>
            @helper.inputText(
            itemForm("title"),
            '_label -> "Titre"  )

            @helper.inputText(
            itemForm("price"),
            '_label -> "Prix"   )

            @helper.select(
            itemForm("category.id"), 
            helper.options(Category.list),
            'id -> "category",
            '_label -> "Categorie")

            @helper.textarea(
            itemForm("content"),
            '_label -> "Description")

            @helper.inputText(
            itemForm("url"),
            '_label -> "URL"    )

            @helper.inputText(
            itemForm("picture"),
            '_label -> "Picture URL"    )

             <input type="submit" value="Ajouter">

        </fieldset>
        }
```

**Admin controller**

```
    (..)
    static play.data.Form<Item> itemForm = form(Item.class);

public static Result newItem(){
    Item item = itemForm.bindFromRequest().get();
    item.save();
    return TODO;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible with the default select helper because you can't override the name attribute and the code to select the correct options would not work with multiple values. Note the name attributes' additional parentheses [] which are neccessary so Play's bindFromRequest method picks up multiple values. You can see that in the Play source, check the bindFromRequest method: [Playframework 2.1 Form class (Java)](http://bit.ly/WbvVix)

This is the view helper I use to handle multiselect fields:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
  <select multiple="multiple" id="@id" name="@{name}[]" size="@{5 min options.length}">
    @for(i <- 0 until options.length) {
        <option id="@id" value="@options(i)._1"  
            @(if(field.indexes.exists(index => field("["+index+"]").value == Some(options(i)._1) ) ) "selected" else "")
        @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) >@options(i)._2</option>      
      }
  </select>
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
@multiselect(itemForm("category"), options(Category.list), '_label -> "Category")
```

This solution works with play 2.1 (scala), I have not tested if it does work with play 2.0 (java)